# can't remove attribute from element

Tags: jquery

I have html like below:
First `<tr>` is displayed based on another function.

```
        <tr style="display: none;">
            <td class="label_column">
            </td>
            <td class="data_column" width="auto">
                <input class="proper_gsc_indexing" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="jest poprawne" data-off="nie jest poprawne" data-size="small"
                           data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" name="proper_gsc_indexing" checked="checked" data-width="200">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="proper_gsc_indexing_list" style="display: none;">
            <td class="label_column">
                Linki
            </td>
            <td width="auto">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="proper_gsc_indexing_list" style="max-width: 75%"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

I'm try to remove style attribute from `<tr>` `.proper_gsc_indexing_list` based on button `.proper_gsc_indexing` state:

```
            if( data.boolean_data.proper_gsc_indexing == true){
                $('[name="proper_gsc_indexing"]').prop('checked', true).change();
            } else {
                $('[name="proper_gsc_indexing"]').prop('checked', false).change();
                console.log('inside');
                $(".proper_gsc_indexing_list").show();
                $(".proper_gsc_indexing_list").css("display", "");
                $(".proper_gsc_indexing_list").removeAttr("style");
            }
```

current state of button value is false, console returns that i'm inside else part of code, but none of attempts to remove style are working.

After load page console shows that `<tr>` element still contains `style="display: none;"`

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder second `<tr>` contains that class `<tr class="proper_gsc_indexing_list" style="display: none;">`

Comment: It's trivial to show that your (original) code, as provided, works fine.  So there must be a reason not provided.  Typically, this might be because your code is running before the element exists (confirm with `console.log($(".proper_gsc_indexing_list").length)` inside your if - if it's `0` then that's the problem).   Alternatively, there may be something running *after* your code to hide it again.  https://jsfiddle.net/so8gxj49/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i try to add code but not all is working as it should. After selecting from first menu there some fields need to by showed like toggle switch . After switching toggle the text field should by appear. Current focus is that: when data from database is saying that switch is off then text area need to by displayed.

Comment: Why are you loading jQuery, Bootstrap, and Bootstrap's CSS 2-3 times each?!

Comment: Your (new) code shows that you add a `.change()` event *inside* another `.change()` event.  If your first (outer) change is called twice you now have 2 inner change events, which call `.toggle` - so you're toggling it on and then off again (or off and on again).  Never add a new event inside another event (unless adding to dynamically added elements, and then better to use event delegation).

Comment: The code in your newly-added snippet is nothing at all like the previous code in the question. Please ensure your question has the code you're actually asking about, and **only** the code you're actually asking about, in as [minimal](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) a form as you can to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: The key part here for the link above ([mcve]) is that it needs to **demonstrate** the problem.  The issue with the first batch of code provided was that that's where you thought the issue was so provided that code - but it clearly worked *on its own*.

Comment: @freedomn-m yep there are 3 change functions one is show/hiding `<tr>` rows second one is show/hide rows based on toggle, and last one is loading data into fields based on another change selection.

Comment: My point being that the two you've shown, 1 is *nested* - this is a sure way for things to not go how you expect them (especially combined with `.toggle`).  Maybe it will be clear when you get you update your snippet to demonstrate so that it demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder con't reproduce the code completely because there is valid data from database that is loaded by ajax code.

Comment: @freedomn-m i have added some code update but ca't ad ajax that will get data from database. Second part of code with if and else is handled based on that data.

Comment: No, you don't reproduce your code here, you reproduce *the issue*.  If there's data loaded via ajax, just set it in a variable up-front.  You've already established/confirmed that it goes into the `else` part, so you don't need the `if` at all, just the `else` part.

Comment: @freedomn-m ajax data is loaded based on another change function that is request is success will load data from database into fields and show hide desired rows.

Comment: @freedomn-m i added another part that contains 'Audyt' the data is also collected form database and based on change the data is loaded into fields with another `$(".audit").change(function()`

Comment: Off topic (probably): What's this all about then?  `for (var key in dict) { try{throw key} catch(key) {`

Comment: @freedomn-m this it for show the rows based on toggle switch and based on key, value data

Comment: @freedomn-m i have noticed that when i set jquery `$(".proper_gsc_indexing_list").show();` outside the `$(".audit").change(function()` then is is working as expected

Comment: @freedomn-m when I put jquery `$(".proper_gsc_indexing_list").show(); ` outside ajax succees then it is working as expected. Problem is that is not working after ajax returns data as JsonResponse back to page.

Comment: "*based on key, value data"* - yes, but why wrap in a try catch? Ah, got it, it's a way to get around the closure for the `setTimeout` - normally you'd do:   `for (var key in dict) { var thisKey = key; setTimeout(function() { .. thisKey .. }`  (or not use setTimeout... it's just odd to add a new event handler inside a setTimeout inside a change event...)

Comment: *outside ajax success* - right, so by going through the [mcve] process, you're narrowing down what the problem is (when it was clear is wasn't `$(".class").show()` as in your original question).  You're getting there.

Comment: @freedomn-m ok i will keep this in mind. Thank You for advice. Do You have any idea why after ajax return success the jquery will not overwrite setup from initial `$(".all").hide()` to `$(".proper_gsc_indexing_list").show();` in same success function?

Comment: Add a (different) console.log next to *all* of the `.hide()` calls and see exactly which order they run.  As `$(".all").hide` is in multiple `if` checks, it's possible it's running a second time?  Again, it's trivial to show that, *in isolation*, .hide() / .show() work fine:  https://jsfiddle.net/so8gxj49/1/

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use `toggle()` instead of `show()`:

```
$(".proper_gsc_indexing_list").toggle('slow');
```